# Can we take time When the user explicitly inputs the location details to google-map in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, time, location

I want to take a time stamp, when user explicitly inputs location details to google-map. Is there any API's in android or can we do this in some other way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: your question is not clear,could you please explain it more...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you meant location details to your app which displays Map in a MapView. Yes you can store the timestamp using System.currentTimeMillis()

Comment: Thanks, my question is when user inputs location coordinates to google-map, i need to capture time stamp in my application.